# Image-pipeline groovy unmet dependencies

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros-groovy, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to install ros-groovy-image-pipeline (sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-image-pipeline) on my beaglebone running ubuntu precise. when i try to install image-pipeline i get the following unmet dependencies.
**ros-groovy-image-pipeline: Depends: ros-groovy-depth-image-proc but it is not installable.**

Any help would be appreciated..
Thank You,
Nav

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67509/image-pipeline-groovy-unmet-dependencies/) by [nav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5434/nav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-17**:
It may be missing temporarily due to repository updates. Try it again?

**Comment by [nav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5434/nav/) on 2013-07-23**:
I tried last night, but got the same unmet dependency ros-groovy-depth-image-proc. I am thinking about downloading source code and compiling it...is this a good idea? Or am i  missing something fundamental with the error above?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-23**:
Building from source is more error-prone. If Ubuntu package installation is not working, you probably have something fundamentally wrong, yet probably easy to fix. Do the basics first: make sure your APT sources are correct, and run `sudo apt-get update`.

**Comment by [nav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5434/nav/) on 2013-07-23**:
thanks, I am sure i tried apt-get update when i initially had the problem, but i will try again tonight...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-23**:
Maybe go back and work through the Ubuntu install instructions one step at a time: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [nav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5434/nav/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thanks for replying, Joq.I followed the instructions for ubuntu for ARM, and ...no luck, still same error. I downloaded source code for image_pipeline and tried rosmake and rosdep install depth_image_proc src. its complaining its unable to get sudo apt-get ros-groovy-pcl-ros..i wonder if this is the underlying issue.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-24**:
I assumed you were using the main Ubuntu repository for i386 and amd64. ARM is a different issue. That repo is experimental and not complete, you might contact @ahendrix about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no compiled version of PCL for ARM; you'll have to build it yourself.

Building PCL from source is tricky and incredibly time-consuming; you may want to seek guidance from other ARM users who have done the same thing. At the very least, make sure the parallelism level is turned down (look for -j options to make and/or ros parallel build cmake variables). This will help limit the amount of memory used during the compile process.

This has been a problem for some months because the older versions of the PCL sourcedebs didn't build on Precise for ARM. I think it's been fixed since then, but my farm is out of date after the rosdistro update and needs some serious work before it will build debs again.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5434/nav/) on 2013-07-26**:
I am trying to compile the source code for pcl, its complaining about ros-groovy-flann. i dont know how much more time i want to invest in this. I think i might focus on opencv purely for my stereo vision needs.
Appreciate the reply and help :)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-07-29**:
There is no compiled build of flann for ARM; you'll have to install that from source as well.  In general, "complaining about" is not specific enough. "complaining that XYZ cannot be found" of "is not installable" is more helpful, and the full command output is even more helpful.

**Comment by [nav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5434/nav/) on 2013-07-29**:
Yeah, there is no compiled version for flann. I am unable to find src for flann, is it part of another package?